# Tools for drawing this graph

Tags: charts

what is the best tool for drawing this kind of graph? I tried in MS Word but they were not as good as this.   [image]

Comment: Excel maybe would be an option (if you live in Microsoft world) or OpenOffice.org Calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Charts, Google Spreadsheets, or Excel would work.  Are you trying to do this programmatically?

Comment: nope. I will be giving some data values I collected

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Spreadsheet tool such as Microsoft Excel, Open Office Calc, Numbers, google docs Spreadsheet ... They are efficient for this task !

Answer (score 0):

Use [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/).  Without any extra settings, gnuplot makes some seriously ugly graphs, but learn just a little, and amazing power is yours.  It handles all kinds of input data rather well, too.  You have a nearly infinite variety of oputput formats as well.